# JavaScript function returning undefined, but logging to the console gets correct values?

Tags: javascript

I don't know how to word this question better, but I have a nested object that I am trying to iterate through and retrieve the values from the `name` key.

[JS Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/sackadelic/9p7kr5tb/28/)

**Example Object:**

```
const colors = {
  blues: {
    "Neutral Blue": {
      name: "Blue" //trying to get this value depth here.
    },

    "Dark Blue": {
      name: "Navy"
    },

    "Light Blue": {
      name: "Azure"
    },

    "Green Blue": {
      name: "Teal"
    }
  },

  greens: {
    "Light Green": {
      name: "Seafoam"
    },

    "Blueish Green": {
      name: "Mint"
    },

    "Grey Green": {
      name: "sage"
    },
  },

  reds: {
    "Light Red": {
      name: "blush"
    },
    "Neutral Red": {
      name: "Scarlett"
    },
    "Dark Red": {
      name: "Merlot"
    },
  },
}
```

I'm trying to run this function here which retrieves a list of the values:

```
let data = Object.values(colors).flatMap((z) => Object.values(z))

const searchNames = (allColors) => {
    
  let colors = Object.values(allColors);
    

  colors.forEach((color) => {
      return color.name //returns undefined
    });
  };
    

console.log(searchNames(data)) //returns undefined
```

However, if I change the return statement to a `console.log(color.name)`, I get the expected result. What am I doing wrong?

A second part of my question would be how to populate an array with all of those values. Thanks for any help.

Comment: `forEach` always returns `undefined`. What is that code supposed to do?

Comment: I was hoping to extract all values from the `name` key, like so: `"Blue", "Navy", "Azure", "Teal", ` etc. I didn't know that about forEach, what is a better way to get all values?

Comment: You can’t return a value inside a forEach it will get discarded

Answer (score 3, accepted):

forEach does not mutate the array. try colors.map()

```
var data = colors.map((color) => {
  return color.name
});
};
console.log(data)
```

Comment: I was able to achieve what I wanted by the following: `return colors.map((a) => a.name)` Thanks to all!

Answer (score 0):

I propose you a solution. Instead create this object:

**Example**

```js
const colors = {
    blues: [{
        label: "Neutral Blue",
        name: "Blue"
    }, {
        label: "Dark Blue",
        name: "Navy"
    }, {
        label: "Light Blue",
        name: "Azure"
    }, {

        label: "Green Blue",
        name: "Teal"
    }],
    greens: [{
        label: "Light Green",
        name: "Seafoam"
    }, {

        label: "Blueish Green",
        name: "Mint"
    }, {

        label: "Grey Green",
        name: "sage"
    }],
    reds: [{
        label: "Light Red",
        name: "blush"
    }, {
        label: "Neutral Red",
        name: "Scarlett"
    }, {
        label: "Dark Red",
        name: "Merlot"
    }]
}
```

Then you can obtain the name key like this.

```js
let names = []
for(key in colors) {
    colors[key].forEach(function(color) {
        names.push(color.name)
    })
}
console.info(names) // this console names array
```